# disappearing .ssh directory on Mac OS X

Tags: mac, ssh

I am experiencing a very strange problem with my desktop iMac running Mac OS X Mojave 10.14.6.

Every night, after midnight sometime:

- the Remote Login item in the Sharing control panel gets unchecked
- the `.ssh` directory in my home directory is deleted entirely

Needless to say, I cannot then ssh to my machine, which I rely on for various reasons.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be going on?  It seems a strange sort of attack to disable Remote Login and remove my .ssh directory.  It is not obvious to me why this would have started, and I have been unable to find any way to prevent it (eg, checking protections, insisting on password for every use of control panel, etc.)

*Addendum* ESET appears to have removed the offending code.  Here are the log entries:

```
10/10/19, 18:32:35  Real-time file system protection    file    /Users/rwh/Library/Application Support/Kuklorest/Kuklorest.app/Contents/MacOS/AppYM a variant of OSX/Adware.Genieo.BH application   cleaned by deleting rwh Event occurred during an attempt to access the file by the application: /System/Library/CoreServices/MRT.app/Contents/MacOS/MRT (484A0A6B9B72E46C8B093D03951BBEBFF785A8F9). 0263B26F29A5BD6DDE47F950FA57ACD42C1BA1AB    31. 7.2018 13:07:09
10/10/19, 18:32:34  Real-time file system protection    file    /Users/rwh/Library/Application Support/com.TotalPanelSearch/TotalPanelSearch    a variant of OSX/TrojanDownloader.Adload.Q trojan   cleaned by deleting rwh Event occurred during an attempt to access the file by the application: /System/Library/CoreServices/MRT.app/Contents/MacOS/MRT (484A0A6B9B72E46C8B093D03951BBEBFF785A8F9). AF7958D6F7F2CFA445EF796127CC93991A098EDD     8.10.2019 15:04:52
10/10/19, 18:32:34  Real-time file system protection    file    /Users/rwh/Library/Application Support/com.TotalPanelSearch/TotalPanelSearch    a variant of OSX/TrojanDownloader.Adload.Q trojan   cleaned by deleting rwh Event occurred during an attempt to run the file by the application: /usr/libexec/xpcproxy (9D87DDC0E1911226AD4E0C5F145FB945F889DE24).  AF7958D6F7F2CFA445EF796127CC93991A098EDD     8.10.2019 15:04:52
10/10/19, 18:32:34  Real-time file system protection    file    /Users/rwh/Library/Application Support/Kuklorest/Kuklorest.app/Contents/MacOS/AppYM a variant of OSX/Adware.Genieo.BH application   cleaned by deleting rwh Event occurred during an attempt to run the file by the application: /usr/libexec/xpcproxy (9D87DDC0E1911226AD4E0C5F145FB945F889DE24).  0263B26F29A5BD6DDE47F950FA57ACD42C1BA1AB    31. 7.2018 13:07:09
10/10/19, 16:17:27  Real-time file system protection    file    /private/tmp/5AA1E95D-4B97-410E-AFF9-9DD28A5A2DEB/1/B842D4C1-BBD2-4AFA-B339-F7BED39D19C3/p  a variant of OSX/TrojanDownloader.Adload.Q trojan   cleaned by deleting     Event occurred on a newly created file. 785B020AC4E27D43ACD7365FF12C83131FF40DA6    10.10.2019 16:17:21
10/10/19, 16:17:27  Real-time file system protection    file    /private/tmp/5AA1E95D-4B97-410E-AFF9-9DD28A5A2DEB/1/B842D4C1-BBD2-4AFA-B339-F7BED39D19C3/p  a variant of OSX/TrojanDownloader.Adload.Q trojan   cleaned by deleting     Event occurred on a newly created file. 785B020AC4E27D43ACD7365FF12C83131FF40DA6    10.10.2019 16:17:21
```

Comment: That really sounds suspicious. Are you running any kind of security software that might be doing automatic security hardening? Have you checked for malware? Have you been running with SIP disabled?

Comment: Apologies, what is meant by "SIP" to be disabled?

Comment: In the Terminal, type "csrutil status" to see if System Integrity Protection (SIP) is enabled or disabled.

Comment: Thanks.  It's enabled, and that hasn't changed.

Comment: Another oddity: sshd and sshd-keygen-wrapper somehow keep getting added to the "Full Disk Access" list under Security&Privacy/Privacy.

Comment: OTOH, having done an ESET protection scan, the problem did not arise last night.  ESET claimed to have "cleaned" three suspicious things.  So we'll see.

Comment: It would appear that the ESET scan resolved the problem; I have had no further difficulties, though there is the mystery of sshd and sshd-keygen-wrapper have been given full disk access rights without my intending to have done that.

Comment: I think it would help others if you would document exactly what three suspicious things ESET "cleaned". I personally would like to learn more about whatever malware this is.

Comment: Appended ESET log to the original message for reference.  Any advice now that the offending code has, apparently, been removed?

Comment: Thanks for the update Robert. If I were you I'd probably consider my SSH private keys to be compromised and regenerate them, and remove/revoke any SSH public keys I'd put on any hosts, including on services like Github. I'd also go verify that my sshd and sshd-keygen-wrapper binaries have the exact same SHA256 value as the ones from a clean install from the same version of macOS. I'd also look through the launchd plist files in /Library/LaunchDaemons, /Library/LaunchAgents, and ~/Library/LaunchAgents, to make sure you know why all of them are there, and check into any ones that seem sketchy.